# Why my next task is not showing when i complete the current task in IBM BPM 8.5

Tags: rest, business-process-management

I assigned the current task using :
https://ustrial01.bpm.ibmcloud.com/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/task/5039918?action=assign&toMe=true

Then Finished the task using:
https://ustrial01.bpm.ibmcloud.com/bpm/dev/rest/bpm/wle/v1/task/5039918?action=finish&parts=all

After finshing the task,
When I do get Task list for user, It is not showing next task in the user, worklist in box. I assigned the next task to same user.

Do i need to do anything to get next task.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In Task->Properties->Implementation-> Select "Automatically flow to next task".

Comment: This is a less than ideal answer.  What this does is block the web thread waiting on the asynchronous start of the next task.  In most cases users should have many tasks in their in box and if they really want to execute separate actions on the same instance one after another you would be better off not modeling this as 2 separate tasks, but rather as 2 UI screens in a single task.